# adding page control to uiscrollview

Tags: iphone

i am trying to add a uipagecontrol to a 2 page slider that has two pictures. I am trying to have two dots that show on which page the user is however I tred to implement this in different ways however i got no solid solution.

Comment: Here's a good tuto : http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html

Comment: thanks i saw this but mine isnt as complex and i cant really use that is there any simple method to just take page width to cause an increase in page number?